# How to find general solution of xdx+ydy=0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

it may be too easy, in a book says

[image]

---

$$x=a\,\cos(t)+b\,\sin(t)\text{ and }y=b\,\cos(t)-a\,\sin(t) $$ satisfy the equation but how do we show these equalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $x \, dx + y \, dy = \dfrac12 d(x^2+y^2)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint：
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=y,\frac{dy}{dt}=-x$$
then we have 
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x=-x$$
that is a differential equation of order 2.
When you have $x$, $y$ is easy to get: $y=\frac{dx}{dt}$.